# How do I make my JButton count and change my display?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jbutton

So I'm working on a somewhat interactive painting of a chess game. Basically, for now, there are only 2 buttons: next move and previous move. The next move button adds 1 to the int variable moveNum, and the previous move button subtracts 1 from the int variable moveNum. Basically like this:

```
int moveNum = 0;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)    
{ 
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Next Move"))
    {
        moveNum++;
        Display.instance.repaint();
    }

    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Previous Move"))
    {
        moveNum--; 
        Display.instance.repaint();   
    }

}
```

I then just have a ton of graphics, one for each value of moveNum. It looks somewhat like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);        

    if (moveNum == 0)
    {
         g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10));//just for simplicity
    }
    else if (moveNum == 1)
    {
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 20, 10));  //again for simplicity
    }
    else if (moveNum ==2)
    {
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 10, 10));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 20, 10));
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 30, 10)); //simplicity
        
    } 
...
}
```

But the graphics are not changing when I press the buttons. What could I be missing?

Update: I have tried to call Display.instance.repaint() after the moveNum stuff, but now I get no graphics at all. What could be the problem?

Update #2: The paint component is being executed because when I put System.out.println("Test"); to the method, it is being printed. I also now see the infinite recursion problem (not sure how I did not see it before). But even after fixing it, I still don't get the graphics I want. I realized that I can get some graphics when I go full-screen for some reason. But the buttons still don't change the graphics. Using the System.out.println("Test"); method, I found that "Test" is printed once when I run the program, two more times when I go full screen and get graphics, and 12 more times when I press the next button. I'm not really sure what's going on there, are my buttons set up incorrectly?

Final update: I do not have a MRE/SSCE, but I have figured out my problem. I have realized I'm one of the biggest idiots in the universe and my problem was capitalization. My buttons were not working because I capitalized the wrong thing in both of them in the segment e.getActionCommand().equals("Next Move")). Anyways, thanks a ton for your help. I don't think I would have found the infinite recursion problem, so special thanks for helping with that.

Comment: 1) NEVER invoke repaint() in a paintComponent() method. 2) in your ActionListener you invoke repaint() on the component that you want to repaint.

Comment: Why should I not have repaint() in a paintComponent() method? I think I was taught specifically to do that...

Comment: Get rid of ALL that `repaint();` code within the `paintComponent` method. In the `actionPerformed` event code block: `if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Next Move")) {
moveNum++; jPanel1.repaint(); } else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Previous move")) { moveNum--; jPanel1.repaint(); }`. This code assumes that your graphics are on a **JPanel**. Correct it accordingly if it is some other component.

Comment: Thank you, I've already done that. Mentioned it in the updates; just forgot to update the code.

Comment: The people trying to help asked some questions that could be answered in a MRE / SSCCE. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Noting an [edit] that provided more uncompilable code snippets, don't do that. Add an MRE / SSCCE.

Comment: @yenchuang Think about it for a minute. Invoking repaint() in the paintComponent() method will cause infinite repainting of the the component. You paint the component then add a paint request to the RepaintManager to paint the component again. This is NOT how painting is scheduled. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `component.repaint()` after `moveNum++;` and after `moveNum--;`.
When `component` is the component that you want to update.

Also, remove the `repaint()` inside `paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Comment: Don't invoke repaint on the frame. You only need to repaint() the component that does the custom painting.

Comment: what does "component" mean?

Comment: you added paintComponent to some class, right? so this class is an component. if you want, you can do repaint for the jframe, but its not efficient

Comment: Both of the methods are in the same class I called display. I set up a frame and then added this display to the jframe. What would be my component then? Would it be the display class?

Comment: somewhere you wrote `new Display()`, the instance is the component. if you don't understand, just repaint the whole jframe. with `jframe.repaint()`

Comment: when I try jframe.repaint(), I get the error "cannot find symbol." The same when I try display(). When I try it with display, I get the error "non-static method repaint() cannot be referenced from a static context" What does this mean?

Comment: This is the best way I could think about to explain: in Display, at the beginning add `public static Display instance;` then, in the constructor of Display, add `instance = this;` and where i said to write `jframe.repaint()` write `Display.instance.repaint();`

Comment: I don't think need to call `actionPerformed()`, if you add `System.out.println("Test");` at the begining of `paintComponent`, is it get printed? also, make sure you aren't calling `repaint()` inside `paintComponent` because then it will be infinite recursion.

Comment: Maybe the place you paint is inside the border of the window, try painting the whole window, also print `moveNum` to make sure that its working correctly.